# Power On/Off assistant responds with "Sorry Power Control is not supported yet"

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I created a project for Google Assist. I have a raspberry Pi4 running
the googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk and it works fine, I can speak and it responds.

But I cant use my "Power On" trait, I have the trait enabled for this device
But when I say "Power On" to the assistant it says back to me
"Sorry Power Control is not supported yet".

I also changed the voice to male but it still plays a female voice. I have re-registered the device but it still doesnt work.

I run

googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id voiceassist-532e2
--device-model-id voiceassist-532e2-pi4assistant-zncdkv

This is the output

Using device model voiceassist-532e2-pi4assistant-zncdkv and device id
d50d3f86-ba00-11eb-ad3b-dca6326e8f6

These are my settings

Project name:VoiceAssist
Project ID:voiceassist-532e2
Product name:Pi4Assistant
Manufacturer:MOB
Model Id:voiceassist-532e2-pi4assistant-zncdkv
Device Type:Speaker
Traits:Brightness , ColorSpectrum , ColorTemperature , Dock , OnOff ,
StartStop , TemperatureSetting